# How to call a function many times automatically?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a `dataframe` with many products A, B, C, D, ...

I created a function from which I can collect data on all products.

But in my file I have many products (20), and I have to call the function for each product.

My function is :

```
# function for prooduct A
function_product(["A"])

df_A_ = pd.DataFrame(file, columns = ['VAR1','VAR2'])

df_A = df_A_[1:]

df_A["Products"] = "A"
```

Do you know how can I automate this function in order to call my code just once instead of 20 times?

Comment: I have no idea whatsoever what your function does. Can you type it following SO instructions plz? (indentation for instance would be appreciated), then describe it a little? IIUC, you have a file already loaded, you create a dataframe for it, erase the first row, and add a column containing the label of your product, is that it?

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop for that, as below:

```
products = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
for product in products:
    function_product([product])
```

The above script will call the `function_product` method for all the products listed in the `products` list.

Comment: thanks EbraHim, 

But it doesn't create all the DataFrame with every products. 
I need to create one dataframe for each products, in order to concate all of them in one Dataframe and make my analysis.

Comment: @BENAMARAILAN You are welcome. If this is what you want, then you can mark it as answer by clicking on the tick mark at the left side of my answer :)

Comment: No it's not what i want, i want to create many dataframes with the functions.

Comment: @BENAMARAILAN So you need to put them inside the loop too.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have your list of products created:

```
list_products = products.split('|')
list_prices = prices.split('|')
```

Then you can create a list containing your dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
list_df = []
for i in range(len(list_products)):
    list_df.append(pd.DataFrame({'product':[list_products[i]],'price':[list_prices[i]]}))
```

Or if you want to create one dataframe containing all prices and products:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'product':list_products,'price':list_prices})
```